# Shell script seems to skip over commands while executing

Tags: linux, bash, shell, raspberry-pi, mtp

I'm trying to create a process where, on detecting my smart watch connecting to it, my Raspberry Pi (4b 2GB) would automatically download new podcast episodes then transfer them to my watch. I have managed to create a udev rule to execute a shell script on detection, but it seems to skip the most vital commands (upodder and mtp-sendfile)? Code below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
PATH=$PATH:/home/pi/.local/bin:/home/pi/.vscode-server/bin/485c41f9460bdb830c4da12c102daff275415b53/bin:/home/pi/.local/bin:/home/pi/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games

echo "Watch connected at $(date)" >>/tmp/scripts.log

# Download new podcasts
/home/pi/.local/bin/upodder

# Transfer podcasts
/usr/bin/mtp-sendfile ~/Downloads/podcasts/WFH_Beckham_Sweden_and_Bango.mp3 /Podcasts

echo "Upodder should've run by now">>/tmp/scripts.log
```

I know that the file runs because /tmp/scripts.log is created and updated, but the podcasts aren't downloaded or transferred. [upodder is a linux podcast downloader](https://github.com/topics/podcast-downloader) and [mtp-tools is a way to transfer files through MTP](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/mtp-tools.1.html). It's pretty clear that the issue is with these two commands but I can't seem to find the solution anywhere. Thanks in advance.

edit: Iruvar suggestion has helped but now I get the error:

```
Unable to determine user's home directory, MTPZ disabled.
Device 0 (VID=091e and PID=4c05) is UNKNOWN in libmtp v1.1.16.
Please report this VID/PID and the device model to the libmtp development team
~/Downloads/podcasts/WFH_Beckham_Sweden_and_Bango.mp3: stat: No such file or directory
```

Seems the issue is with the home directory.

Comment: shell scripts, by default, do not fail fast. You want to add a `2>/tmp/scripts.log` to the download and transfer podcast commands so errors thrown by them are captured in `/tmp/scripts.log`

Comment: @iruvar thanks seems to have helped but now I get a new error.

Comment: I would probably try and find a replacement for MTP; and although it will likely cause me to be viewed as an anachronism here, my first thought would be an FTP server, with lftp as a scriptable client.

Comment: @petrus weirdly the mtp-sendfile command now seems to be working, but the upodder command doesn't seem to do anything.